# Is it possible to install NetBeans under Guest account in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, netbeans, guest-account

Is it possible to install NetBeans under Guest account in Windows 7?
I need to install NetBeans in Windows 7.
It's extremely urgent and when I say urgent I mean urgent... 
I only need to install it today and tomorrow will uninstall it....
Thank you so much for advices!

Comment: If you have tried to install it, and your unable to do so, then you have your answer.  This honestly has everything to do with what permissions you have given the `Guest` account.  I suggest you install NetBeans as an `Administrator` account and configure NetBeans so any user can start it.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to install programs for a guest account.

The statement of microsoft:

> A guest account is an account for users who don't have a permanent
>   account on your computer or domain. It allows people to use your
>   computer without having access to your personal files. People using
>   the guest account can't install software or hardware, change settings,
>   or create a password.
>
> You have to turn on the guest account before it can be used.

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/what-is-a-guest-account)